# Not able to login into sitecore with invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-api, powershell

I need to fetch the data of item with API - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

I am trying this with PowerShell and tried to login like below:

```
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    
    $url = 'https://sc102sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login'
    
    $password = 'b'
    
    $Body = @{
        'Domain'='sitecore'
        'UserName' = 'jagmeet'
        'Password' = $password
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    
    $LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  $url -Method Post -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} `
    -Body $Body -SessionVariable 'Session'
    
    $Session
    
    $LoginResponse
```

but every time, it is throwing an error and not allowing to login:

[image]

In the logs, it says below:

[image]

can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this script to fetch the data of items with API and works well. Try this script.

```
$url = 'https://yourserver/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login'

$Body = @{
    domain = 'sitecore'
    userName = 'admin'
    password = 'b'
}

$json = $Body | convertto-json

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/json' -Method 'POST' -Body $json -usebasicparsing -sessionvariable mysession


$jsonContent = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://yourserver/sitecore/api/ssc/item/8792E70C-E8F1-475C-9AA9-FA57228C8EA1' -WebSession $mysession -METHOD 'GET' -usebasicparsing
$jsonContent.content | convertfrom-json
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So no need to login before running. Thats awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you convert your $Body object to a JSON string which doesn't conform to the Content-Type you state that you're sending. Getting rid of that conversion works for me.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$url = 'https://sc102sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login'

$password = 'b'

$Body = @{
    'Domain'='sitecore'
    'UserName' = 'jagmeet'
    'Password' = $password
}# | ConvertTo-Json

$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  $url -Method Post -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} `
-Body $Body -SessionVariable 'Session'

$Session

$LoginResponse
```